# Binding option left and right arrows to move by words in zsh command line

Tags: shell, zsh, zshrc

I'm using iTerm2 on Mac OSX 10.8 with an `xterm` key binding and `zsh`.

I'd like `zsh` to use option left arrow and option right arrow to do the standard Mac bindings of left and right word.

If I hit ctrl-v then option-left and right arrows, where are the two key sequences that print:

```
^[[1;9D 

^[[1;9C
```

I tried using binding these sequences using `bindkey -v`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 40):

You can configure iTerm2 to do this like so:

- Go to `iTerm2 > Preferences > Profiles > Keys`
- If there is already an `⌥ ←` or `⌥ →` setting, delete it by selecting it and hitting `-`.
- Add a new shortcut by hitting the `+` button.
- Type <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> in the **Keyboard shortcut** box.
- Select `Send Escape Sequence` in the **Action** box.
- Enter `b` for **Characters to send**.
- Click `Ok`.

Repeat the above procedure for `⌥ →`, this time entering `f` for the **Characters to send**.

Taken from this great tutorial which describes the whole process in detail and with pictures:
[Use ⌥ ← and ⌥ → to jump forwards / backwards words in iTerm 2, on OS X | Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/h6yfda)

Comment: Save my issue!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Many thanks!! Was looking for solutions when I just started exploring iTerm2 + zsh lately. And:
1. Delete one word with:
⌥ Delete: Send hex code `0x17`
2. Delete from cursor to beginning of line with:
⌘ Delete: Send hox code `0x15`

Comment: The [solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31979039/260574) is a lot simpler

Answer (score 22):

If you're looking to easily add this and a bundle of similar mappings, there's a "Natural Text Editing" preset under `Preferences > Profiles > Keys` (version 3):

[image]

Comment: Super simple! I got back all the old hotkeys, thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Add the following to .zshrc

```
# Skip forward/back a word with opt-arrow
bindkey '[C' forward-word
bindkey '[D' backward-word
```

Comment: Works great and much more automatable when setting up new machines than having to fiddle with a GUI.

Comment: Agree with the above comment! This is a much more simple and repeatable solution!

Answer (score 3):

Simply add these to your `.zshrc`

```
bindkey "\e[1;3D" backward-word     # ⌥←
bindkey "\e[1;3C" forward-word      # ⌥→
bindkey "^[[1;9D" beginning-of-line # cmd+←
bindkey "^[[1;9C" end-of-line       # cmd+→
```

It works for me using [kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/)